# helm - changing all configmaps during upgrade

Tags: linux, kubernetes, helm

We faced this kind of problem. When we start upgrading via helm - all our configmaps are changed after upgrade.
The question is How to say helm DO NOT change the configmaps during upgrading release?
We want to change configmaps by configmanager.
Thanks everyone for tips!

Comment: btw helm version 3.5.3

Answer (score 1):

as a quick solution make 2 chart.

1. chart for making first install.
   -it contains all configmap
   -You must add anotation configmap.
   annotations:
   "helm.sh/resource-policy": keep
2. chart for helm upgrade.

it doenst have any confimaps. Only deploments
if you install for the first time install your app from chart 1.
To upgrade it use  chart 2.

I belive there is the better way to make it. If someone has any idea=) i will be glad=) THANKS!